# Why data not exporting to csv file in Angular 10 from .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, export-to-csv

I am using .Net Core 3.1 as backend and Angular 10 as front-end.
I want to export csv file there. Right now file is exporting but data not showing in csv file. It's showing data as [object object]. I have checked on google from last few hours and try in my project but failed.

My .Net Core Code is like :

Controller ::

```
public HttpResponseMessage ExportReport()
{
     byte[] carrierPayoutReport = collectReportData();
     var dataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(carrierPayoutReport);
     var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     result.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
     result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
     result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
     {
         FileName = "File.csv"
     };
     return result;
}
```

CollectReport() contains code like below :

```
public byte[] CollectReport()
{
     var output = new byte[] { };
     DataTable dtReportData= new DataTable();
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     //Fetch Data From Database start
     //dtReportData= dbset.Tables[0];
     //Fetch Data From Database End
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
     {
       foreach (DataRow row in dtReportData.Rows)
       {
          writer.WriteLine("Hello")
       }
       writer.Flush();
     }
     stream.Flush();
     output = stream.ToArray();
     return output;
}
```

And Angular Component contains code like below :

```
this.apiService.exportCSV().subscribe(data => {
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI(resp["content"]);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'PayoutCarrier.csv';
hiddenElement.click();
})
```

So with this code csv file is exporting but it's not containing data inside. When I open csv file then it's showing [Object Object] instead of original data. Like attached image [csv file snep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP0XZ.png)
So how to show my data on csv file ?

After suggestion I have set code like below in C# :

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
     {
       foreach (DataRow row in dtReportData.Rows)
       {
          writer.WriteLine("Hello")
       }
       writer.Flush();
       stream.Flush();
       stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     }
     output = stream.ToArray();
     return output;
```

More details about data which I am fetching from database.

Also I have check that if I create file from byte[] and storing file in local system then it's placing all data proper. But when I'm sending it to Angular side then only it's not creating csv file proper.
If file is create from .Net Core then it's creating proper with values but when I am sending byte[] to angular in API response then it's not placing values proper in file.

When I check in console then it's showing response like below :
[console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RojSd.png)

Comment: After writing data to MemoryStream set position to zero before reading.  The stream is at the end so you are reading nothing.

Comment: I have try with "stream.Position = 0" instead of "stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)" but then also it's not showing data in file. It's showing same output [Object Object]

Comment: You should open the csv with notepad, excel may not show data correctly.  Do yo have any rows in the dtReportData?  I do not thing there is any rows.

Comment: @jdweng yes **dtReportData** contains data there. Also I have check file in notepad but same output is showing there.

Comment: Hi @StephanStack,What is your `collectReportData` method? What is your `dataStream` in ExportReport method?And what is your `dtReportData`?Please share more details otherwise we cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Rena I have edit my question and place that how we are getting values in dtReportData. I am getting dtReportData values from store procedure. I have debug my code and check that it's returning proper list of values there.

Comment: What is the following doing : hiddenElement.click()

Comment: It's performing click event on a href and download csv file on angular side

Comment: Hi @StephanStack,Again,What is your `dataStream` in ExportReport method?And in your ExportReport method you called `collectReportData`.What is `collectReportData` method?

Comment: @Rena for checking purpose I was trying with memory stream

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have position the stream in the beginning again after writing to it. You can use the following code to do so:

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

This would go straight before the line

```
output = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: As per suggestion I have update my code with "stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)"  before the "output = stream.ToArray()" then also it's showing me same output in csv file. Still it's showing [Object Object] in file. 
Still there is some mistake in my code so it's not printing proper output there.